# Sql Server pivot table not grouping result set

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, pivot

I have table with values as follows -

```
EMP_CODE | LEAVENAME | APP_TYPE |  LEAVE_DATE | ACT_DAYS
--------------------------------------------------------
ST006    |  CL       | P        | 2012-01-03  | 1.0
ST006    |  CL       | P        | 2012-01-18  | 1.0
ST006    |  SL       | P        | 2012-01-27  | 1.0
ST002    |  CL       | P        | 2012-01-04  | 1.0
ST002    |  CL       | P        | 2012-01-12  | 1.0
ST002    |  SL       | P        | 2012-01-27  | 1.0
OCO038   |  CL       | P        | 2012-01-27  | 1.0
HO188    |  CL       | P        | 2012-01-09  | 1.0
HO188    |  CL       | P        | 2012-01-30  | 1.0
HO085    |  CL       | P        | 2012-01-19  | 1.0
HO085    |  SL       | P        | 2012-01-23  | 1.0
```

I have written this query to sum all leave types as columns for each employee. Each employee must have only one row.

```
SELECT EMP_CODE,[CL],[LWP],[PL],[SL] FROM LEAVE_DETAIL L 
PIVOT (SUM(ACT_DAYS) FOR LEAVENAME IN ([CL],[LWP],[PL],[SL])) 
AS PVT ORDER BY EMP_CODE;
```

But this query is not giving me the expected output. There are more than one row for each employee which is not what I want.

The following table show the expected output -

```
EMP_CODE |  CL  | SL  |
---------|------|-----|
ST006    | 2.0  | 1.0 |
ST002    | 2.0  | 1.0 |
OCO038   | 1.0  | 0.0 |
HO188    | 2.0  | 0.0 |
HO085    | 1.0  | 1.0 |
```

Please help.

Comment: Could you show the output you are actually getting?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't even need the group by in the query. Because what a pivot does is that it "group by" on the other columns. The key to this solution is the inner select. I think it is not a god idé to first do a sum with group by and then apply a sum and a group by again.

```
SELECT 
    EMP_CODE,
    [CL],
    [LWP],
    [PL],
    [SL] 
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
        EMP_CODE, 
        LEAVENAME, 
        ACT_DAYS
    FROM 
        @tmp_emp
) L 
PIVOT
(
    SUM(ACT_DAYS) 
    FOR LEAVENAME IN ([CL],[LWP],[PL],[SL])
) 
AS PVT 
ORDER BY EMP_CODE
```

This will get you the same result.

Comment: Glad to help. I just had to answer because doing something twice is never god for the performance.

Comment: Thanks, this solves my problem. I feel this issue happens when we have more than one measure column exists in the query.

Answer (score 3):

you can try as follow. You can repalce your table as I tested temp table same as your table.

```
create table #tmp_emp (EMP_CODE varchar(10),LEAVENAME char(2), APP_TYPE char(1),LEAVE_DATE datetime,ACT_DAYS decimal(2,1))

insert into #tmp_emp values ('ST006','CL','P ','2012-01-03','1.0');
insert into #tmp_emp values ('ST006','CL','P ','2012-01-18','1.0');
insert into #tmp_emp values ('ST006','SL','P ','2012-01-27','1.0');
insert into #tmp_emp values ('ST002','CL','P ','2012-01-04','1.0');
insert into #tmp_emp values ('ST002','CL','P ','2012-01-12','1.0');
insert into #tmp_emp values ('ST002','SL','P ','2012-01-27','1.0');
insert into #tmp_emp values ('OCO038','CL','P ','2012-01-27','1.0');
insert into #tmp_emp values ('HO188','CL','P ','2012-01-09','1.0');
insert into #tmp_emp values ('HO188','CL','P ','2012-01-30','1.0');
insert into #tmp_emp values ('HO085','CL','P ','2012-01-19','1.0');
insert into #tmp_emp values ('HO085','SL','P ','2012-01-23','1.0');

SELECT EMP_CODE,[CL],[LWP],[PL],[SL] 
FROM 
(
    select EMP_CODE, LEAVENAME, sum(ACT_DAYS) ACT_DAYS
    from #tmp_emp
    group by EMP_CODE, LEAVENAME
) L 
PIVOT (SUM(ACT_DAYS) FOR LEAVENAME IN ([CL],[LWP],[PL],[SL])) 
AS PVT ORDER BY EMP_CODE;
```

Comment: Excellent man. I just missed the point that it had to be grouped before applying the pivot.